# Inherit Permission on New Uplaoded File via FTP

Tags: 14.04, permissions, rsync, chown, chgrp

I am aware that this question is already asked multiple times before on many forums, I have tried to follow the instruction but still not getting it.

I have one Group Called : **`SYNC`** and it has two users `**SAM**` and `**SAM2**`

`**SAM**` is as well the FTP User and Internally users are uploading the files via `**SAM**` FTP user.

SAM2 is the user which is used to run the **`SYNCTHING`** which is used to sync the files between remote location.

but whenever i upload the new files to Directory.SAM2 user doesn't have write access to the new created file so it can not upload the file to the remote location.

**thats how my folder structure and permission look like on the parent directory.**

```
    ls -la For_Client/
total 232312
drwxrwsr-x 2 SAM2 sync      4096 May 23 15:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 SAM2 sync      4096 May 23 12:41 ..
-rw------- 1 SAM sync 237877344 May 23 15:16 test2.mxf
```

**Permission on the newly created File inside the client directory**

```
ls -la For_Client/test2.mxf 
-rw------- 1 SAM sync 237877344 May 23 15:02 For_Client/test2.mxf
```

Please advice, How can i achieve that new created files can inherit the permission from the parent directory and both user can have write access to all directory and files , including newly uploaded by FTP.

Comment: Something is wrong with the output of  `ls -la For_Client/`.  The output shows the same directory with two sets of permissions, this is impossible, please check and correct. One of the lines should be something like `drwxr-xr-x 6 SAM2 sync 4096 May 23 12:41 ..`

Comment: ls -la For_Client/
total 232312
drwxrwsr-x 2 user  sync    4096 May 23 15:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 user  sync     4096 May 23 12:41 ..
-rw------- 1 rtmos syn 237877344 May 23 15:16 test2.mxf

Comment: @mook765, thats the output of `ls -la For_CLIENT`

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1039420/edit) your question to correct the output of your commands. In your comment you show different owner/group for the file `test2.xmf`.

Comment: @mook765, I have reedited the question

Comment: Thanks for quick response, I can't help you more than that, no experience with ftp, could only help with this copy/paste typos, please wait for someone else who can give you an answer.

Comment: @mook765, Thank you for the Help!

Comment: @mook765 , any one please help me out here